# How can I use my domain for google kubernetes engine deployed apps?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gke-networking

I am new at google kubernetes engine. So I am createing a new cluster. And deploying a sample application on this cluster. And I can access it using an ip address like `30.31.32.33/api`
So I want to use my domain name (`mydomain.com or subdomain products.mydomain.com`) for this app

1. Should I set nameserver of domain to ip address `30.31.32.33/api` . Dose this ip address change if recreate the cluster?
2. If I want publish a new app on same cluster with different domain, what can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use a static IP in order to ensure that the IP does not change.
There is a good tutorial on this [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip).

The high level steps:

1. [Reserve a global static external IP address](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip)

   ```
    gcloud compute addresses create $ADDRESS_NAME \
    --global \
    --ip-version IPV4
   ```
2. Create the DNS A record mapping your FQDN to that IP address
3. Use the `kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name` annotation in your Ingress:

   ```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: myapp
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: $ADDRESS_NAME
      labels:
      app: myapp
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: "products.mydomain.com"
        http:
          paths:
            - path: /*
              pathType: ImplementationSpecific
              backend:
                service:
                  name: products-service
                  port:
                  number: 8080
   ```

4. If you want to publish more apps, if they are in separate namespace then just repeat steps 1-3 above for each app.  If you deploy all of the apps in the same namespace, then you can create additional DNS A records for each app and point them to the same IP created in step 1 and then modify the Ingress in step 3 above:

   ```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: myapp
      annotations:
        kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: $ADDRESS_NAME
      labels:
      app: myapp
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: "products.mydomain.com"
        http:
          paths:
            - path: /*
              pathType: ImplementationSpecific
              backend:
                service:
                  name: products-service
                  port:
                  number: 8080
      - host: "app2.mydomain.com"
        http:
          paths:
            - path: /*
              pathType: ImplementationSpecific
              backend:
                service:
                  name: app2-service
                  port:
                  number: 8080
   ```

Answer (score 1):

**Ingress example** for mutople hosts

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-x-host
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: x.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: x
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: y.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: y
            port:
              number: 80
```

> Should I set nameserver of domain to ip address 30.31.32.33/api . Dose
> this ip address change if recreate the cluster?

Not sure how you got that **IP**, if you are using the **LoadBalancer** service it's fine you can use it that way. But will work for a single service or I can say deployment. In another word if you have a single application running this approach is fine.

Yes, I get a change if you **recreate** the **service** but you can use **static IP** also.

> If I want publish a new app on same cluster with a different domain,
> what can I do?

You have to use the **Ingress** object of Kubernetes and **ingress** **controller** to manage the multiple application and expose all those with the different Host name.

Ingress will save your configuration about **host** and **routing**, while the controller will manage **ingress rules**. Once you will install the controller it will give you the same IP that will create the **service type :** **LoadBalancer**. you can map this **IP** to **DNS** with any domain/sub-domain.

There are many different **ingress controllers** available in the market based on usage you can choose any widely used **Nginx ingress controller**, you can also go with the **GCE** if the requirement to use **HTTPS** with **managed SSL** **certificate** from **GCP**.

Here you can refer the example for **Nginx ingress controller** : https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-ingress-gke

What is ingress and Read more about it : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#what-is-ingress

You can also follow this approach without using the **Ingress controller** and have details about **HTTPS** certs etc : https://k8scale-io.medium.com/hosting-multiple-domains-in-gke-ingress-9f8cc61df2ad